# About Plagiarism checking for two academic paper which have been published on conference and journal

Tags: journals, conference, paper-submission

I and my friend have had one paper via a journal([link](https://profdoc.um.ac.ir/articles/a/1020380.pdf)) and conference ([link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5696974)), so as i have seen we have **some mistake** in not adding the desired change on the  journal version of that paper based of [the below rule](https://www.google.com/search?q=hpublsh%20one%20paper%20in%20conference%20and%20journal&oq=hpublsh%20one%20paper%20in%20conference%20and%20journal%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.8866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ( journal version need at least 30% change):

> So, it is okay to develop a previously published conference paper into
> a full-length manuscript and publish it in a journal later on. This is
> an acceptable practice, provided you clearly disclose the conference
> paper and include at least 30% new material in the journal paper

So, now i have seen two paper of someone of our masters via [our previous academic](https://www.um.ac.ir/) on conference and journal ( [paper 1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/732308), [2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/793359)) as you can see [at this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3wvy.jpg).

So, if possible i want to find out **some site** for automatically **check the Plagiarism percentage of academic papers**.

Also, i don't want to use , So i like to find out some way to **check Plagiarism** for this paper without using the [sci-hub.se](https://sci-hub.se) for getting **the PDF version** of the two above papers .

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "plagiarism percentage"?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Any percentage value that some plagiarism checkers give is irrelevant and only used as a guideline for which papers to have a close look at. If you now know that your submitted journal paper does not meet the requirements, you should retract the submission while apologizing. In this way, you can fix your mistake by updating your paper and then submitting it elsewhere sooner (no need to wait for a rejection), without risking that the journal calls you out for your rule violation.

Comment: @DCTLib The way I read OP's question, it's not a merely submitted journal paper, it's one that was already published some years ago.

Comment: Thanks, **@Daniel_Hatton**, I don't get what is the meaning  of `OP's Question`? I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?q=OP%27s+question&oq=OP%27s+question&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but don't get what is the means of `original poster's question` means right now?!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that any plagiarism checker will help you here. First, the 30% rule is not a standard measure, and it is difficult to judge in any case. While it may be a standard for some journal, it isn't 30% of the "words" that is important, but that the new work adds new "ideas" and/or "results" that an editor or reviewer would judge to be about 1/3 of the original.

Plagiarism checkers are very poor tools and are better for checking pure "copying" than for judging advances in scholarship.

Moreover, the journal version will probably have a longer "time in process" than the conference version, permitting you to make changes if the reviewers have issues.

But, ask yourself, what is "new" in the journal version - ideas and results mostly.

---

Note that it is possible to plagiarize using *none* of the original results, simply by paraphrasing the old work without citation. It is the lack of citation that makes in plagiarism, though over-copying can be a different, but still important, offense, perhaps copyright violation.